# Reordering test condition in for-loop: compiler bug?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've got a tree stored in an array, and i'm trying to find a particular node:

```
std::vector<Node> nodes = ...
const unsigned short sentinel = -1;
unsigned short index = 0;
for (Node* node = &nodes[index]; // root node
     index != sentinel;
     node = &nodes[index])
{
    if (foo(*node)) {
       index = node->left;
    } else {
       index = node->right;
    }
}
```

Nothing special, in other words. However, MSVC 2012 fails with an attempt to access `nodes[sentinel]` which is out of range. It turns out that it first calculates `&nodes[index]`, then tests `index`. (Debug mode, no optimizations).

To me, this looks like a code generation bug, but I haven't seen such bugs in at least a decade. It's plain unoptimized code. Sure, even with the rearrangement, `node` isn't actually used before `index` is tested, and it's not terribly unsafe on x86 to have such an out-of-bounds pointer, but MSVC's `vector<>` rightfully asserts on that illegal index.

Did a clean build and checked the assembly again; it's repeatable. The tree isn't empty either, there's always a root node.

Am I overlooking something or is this really a serious compiler bug?

Comment: `nodes[sentinel] ` is `nodes[-1]`, right?

Comment: I don`t see any `nodes[sentinel]` access in the code... but if you Do access that way it will crash(access should be >= 0).

Comment: That's exactly the behaviour I'd expect.  In `for (a;b;c)`, `c` is evaluated before `b` on each iteration (apart from the first).

Comment: Well, `nodes[(unsigned short)-1]`, but equally out of range.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Are you sure? That would mean `for (auto iter = c.begin(), iter != c.end(); ++iter)` would fail on empty containers, for instance.

Comment: @MSalters: That's why I retrospectively added "(apart from the first)" ;)  But other than that, yes.  Consider `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)`.  It iterates 3 times, not 4.

Comment: @MSalters - have you checked that the bug isn't elsewhere in the assignment of the `node->left` or `node->right` index value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code rewritten to a while loop is like

```
Node* node = &nodes[index]; // root node
while(index != sentinel)
{
    {
        if (foo(*node)) {
           index = node->left;
        } else {
           index = node->right;
        }
    }

    node = &nodes[index];
}
```

The last line might be an access to nodes[-1].

I'ld rewrite your loop to

```
unsigned short index = 0;
do
{
    Node* node = &nodes[index];
    if (foo(*node)) {
       index = node->left;
    } else {
       index = node->right;
    }
} while(index != sentinel);
```

Comment: Guess I was put on the wrong track because MSVC put `index` in `EAX` prior to the call of `operator[]` the test of `EAX` after the call but before the use of the `node`.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a for-loop like this:

```
for (init; cond; step) { body; }
```

Then this is the order in which the expressions/statements are executed:

1. init
2. cond; stop on false, otherwise
3. body
4. step
5. cond; stop on false, otherwise
6. body
7. step
8. ...

In other words, it's a synonym for this:

```
{
  init;
  while (cond) {
    body;
    step;
  }
}
```

In your case, it can happen that *body* sets `index` to `sentinel`. You then expect *cond* to execute and break the loop, but notice that after every *body* execution, *step* executes before *cond.* This means that `node = &nodes[index]` will indeed be  executed, with the new value of `index`, which is `sentinel`. So VS is producing what it should.

Your loop seems quite different from a traditional `for` loop; I think it would make more sense to turn it into an explicit `while` loop. If I were doing a code review of your code, I would definitely request that.

Answer (score 2):

"select" Isn't Broken. ;-)

See how the loop is executed.

1. Initialise `Node* node = &nodes[index]`
2. Check index `index != sentinel`. Exit?
3. Loop body. This changes `index`!
4. `node = &nodes[index]`
5. Back to 2.

When after step 3 `index == -1`, you get your out of range access on step 4.

Answer (score 1):

In a `for (init; check; step) { body }` expression, the order goes: `init`, `check`, and then it keeps repeating the cycle `body`, `step`, `check` so `step` occurs before the check.

However, your loop is weird here, because you do not *need* `node` to be involved outside the body!

You can rewrite it easily into:

```
const unsigned short sentinel = -1;
std::vector<Node> nodes = ...

for (unsigned short index = 0; // root node
     index != sentinel;
     )
{
    Node& node = nodes[index];

    if (foo(node)) {
       index = node.left;
    } else {
       index = node.right;
    }
}
```

Which is not only shorter, but also has tighter scope for the variables involved :)

Answer (score -1):

There might be an error (if the author didn't want this behavior) with the sentinel: unsigned short can't be -1;
It should be short... or something signed

Comment: It can but it will be equal to 65535. But it is still a bug

Comment: Well, depends exactly of what the author wants to do, but I had to point it out so we are sure we don't miss something

Comment: `unsigned short` -1 isn't 65535; it's `~static_cast<unsigned short>(0)`.

Comment: In general, it will be equal to `USHORT_MAX`, which is _at least_ 65535, but on MSVC2012 it's indeed exactly 65535. BTW, not that it matters: I've got about 10.000 nodes in this particular tree. Accessing [-1] is just as fatal as [65535].

Comment: This is a good comment, but it is not an answer to the question.